# Logi analytic integration with rails application for single sign on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration

Is it possible to integrate Logi analytic with a rails application for single sign on feature ?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for long time, I found the following link useful.

What I have understood till now is that it is not possible to create a Logi application using ruby. An existing rails application can be used for SSO feature with Logi application.

Following link is useful.
http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1126