# Single signon, authorization using logianalytics in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, windows, devise

I want to integrate **Logi Analytics for single sign-on(sso) , authentication and authorization** in rails web application using SecureKey for single sign on(sso).
http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1205

I am using devise and cancan for authentication and authorization, and linux based system(Ubuntu) for development.

Solution should be in Ubuntu and web.

Some reference to help :
http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1209#Ruby

Comment: Need more context... Can you tell where you are facing issue?
or you are asking for guide/tips?

Comment: I am not facing any issue. I want Guidance to use Logi Analytics on ROR for SSO.

Comment: I think following is what you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426295/logi-analytic-integration-with-rails-application-for-single-sign-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following comment of @Hardik is useful.

> I think following is what you are looking for [stackoverflow.com/questions/21426295](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426295/)… –  Hardik Mar 31 '14 at 11:55